# how can i get the reply of text message on some perticular number with info using nexmo api

Tags: vonage

I am using the nexmo api for send text message.Now my requirement is like when i will send the message to somebody then it will reply on some perticular number like XXXX.So i can run some api for checking anybody have make response with some information like userid,message time and other custome parameter.I have refer this link 
  [1]: https://docs.nexmo.com/ but i have not get any shortcode on which i can get reply of message.So anybody have idea how can i fulfill my requirement?Or does nexmo provide the shortcode?
Thanks in advance.
[nexmo document][1]

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a virtual number from Nexmo, and use that to collect replies. Just use that number as the `from` when sending outbound messages.

Here are the [Nexmo docs](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/handle-inbound-message) on inbound messages.

*[Disclaimer: I work for Nexmo.]*